# Canceling installation from an External UI

Tags: installation, wix, windows-installer, dtf

I have created an C# application that installs MSI's by calling [Installer.InstallProduct](http://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/aa369428%28v=vs.85%29.aspx). I have set the application to be the "external UI" by calling [Installer.SetExternalUI](http://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/aa370384%28v=vs.85%29.aspx) and passing an `ExternalUIHandler`. The MSIs are set to install silently.

Here's my code:

```
    Installer.EnableLog(InstallLogModes.Verbose, "install.log", true, true);

    Installer.SetInternalUI(InstallUIOptions.Silent);

    Installer.SetExternalUI(OnUIUpdate, InstallLogModes.Progress);

    using (Transaction scope = new Transaction("Transaction1", TransactionAttributes.None))
    {
        foreach (string msi in Installers)
        {
            Installer.InstallProduct(msi, "");
        }
    }
```

Question:

How do I send a "CANCEL" message from an external UI using DTF to cancel the on-going installation?

Answer (score 0):

Return MessageResult.Cancel from the UI callback.

Comment: I understand what you're saying but can you provide a code sample?